# Unable to access attr id within a focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm not sure why I'm unable to access a $(this).attr(id) within a focus event. I am setting it within a variable but am getting undefined when I try to see what value was stored. Not entirely sure what is going wrong here. I am using a library called 'Horsey' which enables you to easily integrate autocomplete into your application. See docs for that here: https://github.com/bevacqua/horsey/

Here is the code in question:

```
$( "input" ).focus(function() {
            var curr_input_id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            horsey(document.querySelector(curr_input_id), {
              suggestions: [<? echo $this->Video_model->get_all_tag_names(); ?>]
            });
});
```

This is the full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Dashboard - Snipptr | Uploaded Videos</title><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/bootstrap.fd.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/dropzone.min.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/horsey.min.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/custom.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/logo.png'; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'subscriber'; ?>">Basic Stats<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'subscriber/videos'; ?>">Uploaded Videos</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="<?php //echo base_url().'subscriber/suggested'; ?>">Suggested Snippets</a></li> -->
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'subscriber/pending_snippets'; ?>">0 New Snippets</a></li>
        <li class="open_button"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Upload Video(s)</button></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account (50/50 credits - $250) <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Add Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Billing</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'auth/logout'; ?>">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Page Header -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Your Uploaded Videos (<? echo $video_number; ?>)
                    <small>Snippets Pending: 0 - Snippets Approved: 0</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->           

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
             <?php 
                foreach ($videos as $video)
                { ?>
                   <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                        <video id="really-cool-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
                         preload="auto" width="358" height="264" poster="really-cool-video-poster.jpg"
                         data-setup='{}'>
                          <source src="<?php echo s3_site_url("subscriber_videos/".$video->s3_file_name); ?>" type='<? echo $this->Video_model->format_mime_type($video->mime_type); ?>'>                         
                          <p class="vjs-no-js">
                            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser
                            that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                          </p>
                        </video>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php echo s3_site_url("subscriber_videos/".$video->s3_file_name); ?>"><? echo $video->file_name; ?></a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Write a general (140 word) description of this video here. Make this a text area.</p>
                        <p><input class='tags_input_area' id='tags_<? echo $video->id; ?>' type="text" value="<? echo $this->Video_model->get_tag_names($video->tags); ?>" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Enter your tags here."></p>
                        <? if ($video->active == 0)
                           {
                                $checked = '';
                           }
                           else
                           {
                                $checked = 'checked';
                           }
                        ?>
                        <input <? echo $checked; ?> data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" type="checkbox" id="active_switch_<? echo $video->id; ?>" class="active_switches"> 
                        <? /*if ($checked == 'checked') {
                            echo ' Finding Snippeters...';
                        }*/                     
                        ?> 
                        <hr>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'subscriber/pending_snippets/'.$video->id; ?>">(New) Pending Snippets (<? echo $this->Video_model->get_submitted_snippets($video->id, 1); ?>)</a> - <a href="<?php echo base_url().'subscriber/approved_snippets/'.$video->id; ?>">Accepted Snippets (<? echo $this->Video_model->get_accepted_snippets($video->id, 1); ?>)</a>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                }
            ?>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

<!-- line modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">Upload Video(s)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- content goes here -->
            <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="<?php echo base_url().'subscriber/upload_video'; ?>" class="dropzone bfd-dropfield-inner"></form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-delete hidden" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="delImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-red" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Delete</button>
                </div>
                <!--
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Save</button>
                </div>
-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'; ?>" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/dropzone.min.js'; ?>" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js'; ?>" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/horsey.min.js'; ?>" type="text/javascript">
    </script>    

    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {    
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            video_id = id.replace('active_switch_','');
            var check = $(this).prop('checked');
            if (check)
            {
                t = 1;              
            }
            else {
                t = 0;
            }
            $.get( "active_switch/" + video_id + "/" + t, function( data ) {
              console.log( data + "." );
            });        
        });

        u = '<? echo base_url(); ?>' + 'subscriber/';

        $('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
            tag_name = event.item;
            vid_id = $(this).attr('id');
            real_vid_id = vid_id.replace('tags_','');
            $.post( u + "add_tag", { tag_name: tag_name, video_id: real_vid_id })
              .done(function( data ) {
                //alert( data );
            });
        });

        $('input').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
            tag_name = event.item;
            //alert(tag_name);
            vid_id = $(this).attr('id');
            real_vid_id = vid_id.replace('tags_','');
            $.post( u + "delete_tag", { tag_name: tag_name, video_id: real_vid_id })
              .done(function( data ) {
                //alert( data );
            });
        });

        /*
$('input .tags_input_area').tagsinput({
          typeaheadjs: {
            source: function(query) {
              return $.get(u + 'get_all_tags');
           }
          } 
        });
*/      

        $( "input" ).focus(function() {
            horsey(document.querySelector('input'), {
              suggestions: [<? echo $this->Video_model->get_all_tag_names(); ?>]
            });
        });

        $(".portfolio-item h3 a").text(function(index, currentText) {
            if (currentText.length >= 27)
            {
                return currentText.substr(0, 27) + '...';
            }

        });

    });     

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error are you getting or what is happening specifically?

Comment: the jQuery seems fine. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3py3jLsg/) . Are you able to `alert` at all? Perhaps provide the HTML created so we can now what youre working with.

Comment: try `document.querySelector("#"+curr_input_id)`

Comment: the response when I do an alert is actually 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you share the HTML as well? This should be a stupid question but are you sure the focused input has an id attribute?

Comment: Well i am using a lib called bootstrap-tags-input, which modifies the input on focus so that might be it. I will share the html.

Comment: I have added the html.